# How to programmatically set the audio balance (panning, L/R) on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, audio

I would like to set the audio balance settings (panning, L/R) programmatically. It is possible to adjust this setting manually, via the Android/iOS settings.

For example on ios:
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/mono-audio-balance-phone-noise-cancellation-iph3e2e2cdc/ios

I am aware that it is possible to control this for audio generated by my app. However, I would like to control the system wide settings.

Comment: You could try setMasterBalance() of this class. Try to use reflection if it's hidden https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. However I can't seem to be able to import that. Tried: `import android.media.AudioSystem`. Do you know how I can import that?

Comment: Please try to access this class using so called Java *reflection*.

Comment: I tried to do this:

```
val AudioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem")

val setMasterBalance = AudioSystemClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMasterBalance", Float::class.java)
setMasterBalance.isAccessible = true
        
val getMasterBalance = AudioSystemClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMasterBalance")
getMasterBalance.isAccessible = true

setMasterBalance.invoke(null, 0.5f)
val masterBalance = getMasterBalance.invoke(null)
```

I get this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getMasterBalance []`
I am targeting API 32.
What am I doing wrong?